# Keep ComboBox popup open after selecting an item

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I'm working on a custom ComboBox control in WPF. Basically I have a list of items in the ComboBox, and when an item is selected, it gets removed from the ComboBox and added to a separate ItemsControl. The user may need to select more than one item, so I would like to keep the ComboBox open after an item is clicked, but it closes automatically. Is there any way to override this behavior?

Comment: You could go with the usual UX style for this kind scenario, where you will have two listboxes/itemscontrol and move items between them. Refer to [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/what-is-the-best-ui-for-multi-selecting-from-a-list)

Comment: I thought about something like this but I kind of want the first list hidden until the user needs to interact with it. I could just have a popup that opens on a button click or something similar, but at that point it feels like it should just be a ComboBox :)

Comment: Did you simply try opeing it?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried setting IsDropDownOpen = True in the ComboBox's SelectionChanged event. Nothing happened, since IsDropDownOpen was still True. I then tried setting it like this: "Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() IsDropDownOpen = True)" to push it onto the UI thread stack, and this somewhat worked, except it closes and reopens, which I don't want. I am hoping to get it to just stay open.

Comment: You should post what you have tried